# CLI command being overridden? visual-studio-code is installed alongside sublime text but the CLI command `code` only opens sublime

Tags: command-line, text-editor, sublime-text, visual-studio-code

I am trying to give visual-studio-code a go to see if it would be a good code editor for me.  So I have it installed.  However, I also already had/have Sublime Text 3 installed.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get vscode to run from the CLI/terminal.

Running:

```
code README.md
```

Opens up a README in sublime.

Yet when I do `which code` => /usr/bin/code => /usr/share/code/bin/code the files in /usr/share/code have license text files for VSCode:

```
$ head -3 /usr/share/code/resources/app/LICENSE.txt 
MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS
MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO CODE 
...
```

What I have tried:

I uninstalled vscode:

```
sudo apt remove --purge code
sudo apt install code
```

And yet running `code someTextFile.txt` (or `/usr/bin/code` or `/usr/share/code/bin/code`) still opens sublime instead of vscode.

How can I fix the command to allow me to run vscode to open code files from the CLI?

Comment: Add the output of `type -a code` to the post, please

Comment: Thanks @muru That solves my problem, it is referencing a function still present somewhere:
type -a code
code is a function
code () 
{ 
    command subl "$@" & disown
}
code is /usr/bin/code
Wasn't aware of type -a command, thanks!

Comment: Now I just have to track down where I have that function.

Comment: Try https://superuser.com/a/229038

Comment: That's got it, it was a combination of an alias referencing code and a function masking that alias, make this an answer and I'll certainly accept it:
run: make -a yourCommandHere to find out where the command is coming from, then to find where it is, if it is a function:
shopt -s extdebug;declare -F yourFunctionHere;shopt -u extdebug

Comment: A more useful answer would be the origin of that alias and function. You can post that, with the `type -a` etc. as steps leading to their discovery.

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to find this due to the comments above for debugging commands. The source of this issue ended up being the following:

I had an alias that looked like this:

```
alias e="code"
```

Then later on I had a function that was mapping:

function e() {
     subl
}

Which was overriding the alias.  So a search for "code" found the alias that I expected, but since apparently functions get checked first, it was still calling for the function `e` instead of the alias.